# Ignore exception and add file to a list?

Tags: c#, attributes, readonly

I asked a question yesterday, and recieved great help (especially from @AviTurner).

I have further developed the program I was working on yesterday, and I have encountered a new problem.

The code of my program can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/74kXhvbi).

Basicly what it does, is:

The user can select a path of a directory, and the program scans all files for read-only attribute.

It sets the read-only attribute on those files that does not currently have it.

Now the problem occurs, when it encounters a file that is currently in use (such as system files).

I have been told there is no way around this, but I thought:

Is there a way to ignore the error (by this I mean continue the program, just skip this file); and add the name of the file to a list for later tracking purposes?

I hope I made my problem clear.

Thanks.

Comment: @wudzik am I supposed to do a `catch(Exception)` and then put brackets around the piece of code that gives the errors?

I have never used the catch function before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try surrounding your code in try/catch:

```
try
{
    System.IO.FileAttributes attr = System.IO.File.GetAttributes(file);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    files.add(file)
}
```

basically if you get an exception in the try block, the program executes the catch block

Comment: I have tried doing this; however it gives me another issue. 

Now I get the errors "The name 'attr' does not exist in the currenct context. I think this is because 'attr' is declared in the parent scope(correct??).

How can I help this?

Comment: oh, right... just paste all the rest of the code that uses the attr into the try block

Comment: Oh I see. now it Works. Thanks a lot. I understand how try/catch Works now.

My catch looks like this now:

`catch (Exception Ex)
                {
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(2, 2);
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red; 
                    Console.WriteLine("There was an error changing the attributes of a file");
                    errorfiles.Add(file);
                }`

Will this correctly add the file to the list "errorfiles"?

Comment: seems like, glad i could help!

Comment: Hmm.. Something does not work. [this](http://pastebin.com/rtR7uZga) piece of code is giving errors. When I run my program, it gets an exception and stops @ the `foreach (string file in System.IO.Directory` etc etc. (check my link above for refference), and says there was an error retrieving information of a file, because of denied acces.

So I figured I would put a try/catch around this too, but I want it to continue the foreach loop, just now skipping the file that was 'catched'.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest...

```
try
{
    System.IO.File.SetAttributes(file, attr);
}
catch // You can specify a specific error with catch(UnauthorizedAccessException ex) for instance.
{
    filesInError.Add(file); // A list<string>() to keep track of errors.
}
```

Here the details, and exceptions raised, by the SetAttributes().
[SetAttributes on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.io.file.setattributes%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

And some explanations about try catch if you're not familiar with.
[try ... catch on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/0yd65esw%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)